# sybase ase giving different result set for the same query

Tags: sybase

I am firing a same select query with different logins. And the result set is different for different login ids.
I have a script which i ran with dbo permission which is inserting 3 rows intoa table xyz. Now when I query the table with same user id that is the dbo i get the result as expected which contains the newly inserted rows.But when i query the same table with another credential used by the end user the extra three records are not fetched.
Is it that data will be based on the role or the login id?

Comment: check if schema you using is same. Had similar problems shema1.tablename and schema2.tablename

Comment: same schema... this happens everytime when we use different username. Dont know why

Comment: could you add table creation and data insertion scripts? Also what product you are using?